# What's the fastest way to calculate log of a power of 32?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, persistent-data

Given that the language is javascript, and that the input is `< 1073741824`, what's the fastest way to obtain the equivalent to:

```
Math.floor(Math.log(len) / Math.log(32))
```

I've tried with an if:

```
if (len < 1024) return 1;
if (len < 32768) return 2;
if (len < 1048576) return 3;
if (len < 33554432) return 4;
if (len < 1073741824) return 5;
```

and with bitwise operators:

```
// 0000000000000000000000000100000 // 32
// 0000000000000000000010000000000 // 1024
// 0000000000000001000000000000000 // 32768
// 0000000000100000000000000000000 // 1048576
// 0000010000000000000000000000000 // 33554432
// 1000000000000000000000000000000 // 1073741824
function log32(len) {
    return (
        0 + 
        !!(len >>> 30) + 
        !!(len >>> 25) + 
        !!(len >>> 20) + 
        !!(len >>> 15) + 
        !!(len >>> 10) +
        !!(len >>> 5
    )
}
```

is there a way to do this cleaner or with less ops?
(performance measured with: https://jsperf.com/log32-perf/)

Comment: What about [bit twiddling hack](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog)?

Comment: What do you consider to be wrong with your `if` cascade approach?  I can't imagine a *faster* way, or a way with fewer ops, even if it looks hacky or mathematically inelegant.  (BTW given your initial assumption, that the input is always less than 1073741824, you don't even need the final comparison operation and `if` conditional—just `return 5;` would do it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go for the very efficient [`Math.clz32`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/clz32) method, which returns the number of leading zero bits in the 32-bit binary representation of a number.

```js
const log32 = x => Math.floor((31 - Math.clz32(x))/5);

console.log(log32(1023)); // 1
console.log(log32(1024)); // 2
```

This will return the correct value for any x > 0 within the 32-bit range.

Comment: Nice +one; better than log2(). Btw you can replace `/5` with `*0.2` which is generally faster.

Comment: impressive +1. if we trade Math.floor for result | 0 we can shave another hair., which then measures faster than my if

Comment: In FF I don't get any significant improvement with `*0.2`, nor with `|0`: either solution comes out fastest about 50% of the time.